# how to set color to indeterminate checkbox

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How do we set color to checkbox depending on state? Any idea guys ?

the default color of my checkbox is color="primary" if checkbox is indeterminate it should disabled the color primary and will show the default color of indeterminate

Thanks.

if the checkbox value is true the color should be primary - which is the sample below

[image]

if the checkbox is value is false it should be like this

[image]

my current problem is that when its indeterminate the current color result is this

[image]

#html

```
   <mat-checkbox 
                        [indeterminate]="!data.isCriticalPath" (change)="checkState(data,$event,'isCriticalPath')"
                        [(ngModel)]="data.isCriticalPath" color="primary"></mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: I dont't see that this is a problem. The most common use case for indeterminate state of a checkbox is when you have for example a Select All option in a list of checkboxes. If you select some options, not all the options, the indeterminate state will show in Select All option. A common case could be with the days of the week list with checkboxes. You could include a Select All option to it. I think that the best UX is to have marked as primary if there are some options selected.

Comment: Why is the best option to marked as primary? Because the user must note that is possible to click on this option to mark/unmark. If you colorize it like you are suggesting it could be miss leading for the user since this way seems like is disable so it is not possible to click it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Eknot mentioned the right way. You just need to toggle a class in your checkbox element depends on a state like this:

```html
<mat-checkbox 
  [class.intermediate]="!data.isCriticalPath"
  [indeterminate]="!data.isCriticalPath"
  (change)="checkState(data,$event,'isCriticalPath')"
  [(ngModel)]="data.isCriticalPath" color="primary">
</mat-checkbox>
```

And in your `css` file:

```css
::ng-deep .intermediate .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: #b5b5b5 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Angular Material you can set the color via the color directive or specific parts via css. But watch out, you have to set Material css on the top level of your css hirachy or by using `::ng-deep`.

Example:

```css
::ng-deep mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-checkmark-path {
    stroke: red !important;
}
```

Checkout the Material Docs https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/api

Comment: Question Sir , what I dont understand is how do I apply to the my concern above ? cause the color of the checkbox depends on the state of the checkbox , if its false it should be grey like the screenshot above , if its true then should be like the color above which is blue.

Comment: the default color of my checkbox is color="primary" if checkbox is indeterminate it should disabled the color primary and will show the default color of indeterminate